# JS filter array of objects by a nested array within object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, filtering

I have an array of objects similar to this

```
 let data = [
      {
        name: 'jake fisher',
        age: 24,
        team_ids: [1234, 5678, 9125],
      },

      {
        name: 'kelly smith',
        age: 46,
        team_ids: [3331, 8884, 1234, 8808, 7621],
      },

      {
        name: 'austin williams',
        age: 66,
        team_ids: [9125, 4445],
      },

      {
        name: 'alex rodriguez',
        age: 27,
        team_ids: [],
      },
    ];
```

i'm trying to filter this array of objects to only be objects that contain a team_ids number of 1234
so in this example, the only two that would have a team ID that matches are "Jake Fisher" and "Kelly Smith".

I've tried a handful of other solutions, some getting me fairly close but seem to have some serious flaws. I think what's really throwing me off is the fact that it's a nested array (I'm learning and i've not run into this very often!) Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Look into "filter" and "includes" methods in Javascript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
let data = [{
    name: 'jake fisher',
    age: 24,
    team_ids: [1234, 5678, 9125],
  },

  {
    name: 'kelly smith',
    age: 46,
    team_ids: [3331, 8884, 1234, 8808, 7621],
  },

  {
    name: 'austin williams',
    age: 66,
    team_ids: [9125, 4445],
  },

  {
    name: 'alex rodriguez',
    age: 27,
    team_ids: [],
  },
];

const result = data.filter(item => item.team_ids.indexOf(1234) !== -1)
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let data = [{
    name: 'jake fisher',
    age: 24,
    team_ids: [1234, 5678, 9125],
  },

  {
    name: 'kelly smith',
    age: 46,
    team_ids: [3331, 8884, 1234, 8808, 7621],
  },

  {
    name: 'austin williams',
    age: 66,
    team_ids: [9125, 4445],
  },

  {
    name: 'alex rodriguez',
    age: 27,
    team_ids: [],
  },
];

const result = data.filter(item => item.team_ids.includes(1234));
console.log(result);
```